# IdentityServer4 endsession redirecting to account/logout giving 404

Tags: angular, identityserver4, angular-oauth2-oidc

I have IdentityServer4 running in Azure on an https url, and I'm using an Angular CLI project with [the angular-oauth2-oidc library](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) to handle the Implicit Flow. I'm trying to set up Single Sign Out, but it's not working correctly.

I'm calling [`logOut` on the `OAuthService`](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/injectables/OAuthService.html#logOut) which was auto-configured (via the Discovery Document) to use a logout url on the auth server, i.e. `https://my-id4-server.example.com/connect/endsession` with query string parameters containing a `token_hint` and a `postLogoutUri`.

For some reason, the **actual behavior** is that IdentityServer4 redirects (**302**) the browser to the url `https://my-id4-server.example.com/account/logout?logoutid=...`, for which the browser gets a **404**. In addition, if I open the IdentityServer pages in a separate tab, I can see my session is still alive.

The **expected behavior** is that my session is ended, and that I get redirected back to my SPA.

On the ID4Server side I've configured:

- `RedirectUris` and `PostLogoutRedirectUris` with `http://localhost:4200` (where my SPA runs currently), amongst others;
- `AllowedGrantTypes` is set to `Implicit`
- `AllowedCorsOrigins` also allows my localhost SPA

In addition I can see the `endsession` endpoint correctly configured in the `.well-known` configuration endpoint.

On the SPA side I've configured `issuer`, `redirectUri`, `clientId`, and `scope`. Logging in with a redirect back works just fine.

---

Bottom line: what is wrong if the `endsession` endpoint redirects to `account/logout` which in turn gives a 404?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Controller action for [`Logout(...)`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L224) was missing on the IdentityServer side of things. If you don't have those but everything else *is* there, then you get said behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that `account/logout` is the default redirect for this flow and you need to either change it to your actual logout URL in the IDS4 settings or simply implement that endpoint.

It's by design that IDS4 hands control over to you after the endsession endpoint is hit. You get passed a `logoutid` param which you can then use in combination with IIdentityServerInteractionService to get information  about the endsession request and take the necessary action - e.g. prompt for confirmation, load the front channel logout iframe, deal with signing out of an external IDP etc.